# Java Area.subtract method taking really long time on shapes with same geometry

Tags: java, awt, java-2d

Just a general inquiry. I'm testing out a symmetry detection system that I wrote and I appear to come across on issue with the java.awt.geom.Area class. Specifically, I'm testing the vertical symmetry (or symmetry about the x-axis) of the following object

[image]

You can see that this panel has a vertical symmetry. To calculate this, I make the GeneralPath of this object (call it originalPath), then flip it about its center in the y to get the symmetric path (call it symmetryPath). I then perform:

```
public boolean hasSymmetry(GeneralPath originalPath, GeneralPath pathToCheck) {
    Area originalArea = new Area(originalPath);
    Area areaToCheck = new Area(pathToCheck);

    areaToCheck.subtract(originalArea)

    return symmetryArea.isEmpty();
}
```

Unfortunately, when I run this on this panel, the subtract call takes a really long time; far more than it should.

Has anyone come across this before. One of my colleagues remembers a time ago when this happened to him and at the time the fixed was to make sure all GeneralPaths were closed (must be some numerical issues interally in the Area.subtract method that struggles when paths are close to being closed). So I made sure all paths were closed, but to no avail. Still takes forever it seems.

Any hints/suggestions/insights would be greatly appreciated.

Btw, here is a screenshot of the two GeneralPaths (original and transformed) drawn one on top of other. You can see they're pretty equal:

[image]

Comment: I'd try to reproduce this, but before investing (potentially lots of) time in order to (potentially) just find out that I can't reproduce this: Is there an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for this, or can I just try it with some `Path2D` that describes a "100-sided regular polygon" (i.e. a circle that was created with a flattening `PathIterator`)? (Assuming that it does not have to be a `GeneralPath`....)

Comment: Hello Marco, I'm also trying to find a smaller test case in which this occurs to try and simplify my investigation but have yet to find one. If I do, I will repost immediately. I'm unsure whether it is tailored specifically to GeneralPaths, or whether its a general issue that can be reproduce with any Path2D.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). @Marco13 Did you know that `[mcve]` (without the code formatting) auto-expands to [mcve]? ;)

Comment: I tried it with a very simple example, but did not notice anything unusual. Of course, the `Area`-based computations **can** be expensive, because there's some really sophisticated constructive geometry processing magic going on internally. But I'm not sure what *"... long time; far more than it should."* means in this case. If the problem was described more precisely, it **might** be possible to find a (far) more efficient solution - e.g. simply comparing points that are delivered by a `PathIterator`. Also note that the current method does **not** detect symmetry, but only "containedness"